# Issue installing Microsoft Azure Storage Library for PHP via composer

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage

we are trying to install [Microsoft Azure Storage Library for PHP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php) but getting some weird errors which we googled and it returned nothing, here is what we did

1. Cloned the repo from github
2. composer install (see image for error)

[image: screen after composer install]

here is what we got as result of that(for seo purpose or in case image is not loaded correctly)

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - theseer/phpdox 0.8.1.1 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - theseer/phpdox 0.8.1 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - theseer/phpdox 0.8.0 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for theseer/phpdox ~0.8 -> satisfiable by theseer/phpdox[0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.1.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

---

After this as instructed we ran `php --ini`

[image: after running php --ini]

here is the exact output(for seo or image not loaded properly)

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

Now according to our assumption, required extensions are there but we are unable to find what exactly is the problem.

Comment: According your error message, the dependency requires `xsl` extension, but which you haven't installed or enabled in your PHP runtime. Can you make sure you have enabled the `xsl` extension in your PHP runtime?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT i got overwhelmed by those errors that i ignored `the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system` this line, thanks mate for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Ok so all those errors have one hidden line in them `the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system` which i somehow didn't see due to the size of this error, in case you are struggling, here is what you should do

1. check if `xsl` is enabled by typing in your command line `php -m`
   now this is going to give huge list, make sure if `xsl` is there, if not follow step 2
2. If `xsl` is not enabled / installed type this command `sudo apt-get insitall php5-xsl` and after that make sure it is enabled by typing `php -m`

hope it will save your six hours :)